# VPN PPTP Connection with only enable CHAP

Tags: internet, vpn

I have problems with my VPN connection. I hope there is someone who can help me.

I need a VPN conncetion. I already have this conncetion established whttp://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-helpith Ubuntu. There I only enabled CHAP. I wanted to do the same on my Raspberry but there I am not able to. I cannot disable PAP and EAP without enabling MSCHAP. I do not know what to do, can someone help me here?

Because of having so many problems, I also tried to connect manually with pptpsetup. My /etc/ppp/peers/wohnheim file is:

```
written by pptpsetup
pty "pptp 172.16.185.2 --nolaunchpppd --debug"
lock
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
name username
remotename wohnheim
ipparam wohnheim
refuse-pap
refuse-mschap
refuse-mschap-v2
refuse-eap
require-chap
noauth
persist
maxfail 0
```

The /etc/ppp/chap-secrets is:

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses

# added by pptpsetup for wohnheim
username wohnheim "password" *
```

What do I have to change or to add to get a working VPN connection?